# mail works when sent to gmail, doesn't when sent to yahoo

Tags: php, email

I have a standard code for sending e-mails as verification process. All works fine when I register with gmail address (email comes instantly). When I register with yahoo, nothing. Waited for days, nothing. No spam, simply graveyard.

my configuration:

```
mail.add_x_header   On  On
mail.force_extra_parameters no value    no value
mail.log    no value    no value
sendmail_from   no value    no value
sendmail_path   /usr/bin/php -C --php-ini /etc/php-console.ini /var/mailer2/mailer.php  /usr/bin/php -C --php-ini /etc/php-console.ini /var/mailer2/mailer.php
Path to sendmail    /usr/bin/php -C --php-ini /etc/php-console.ini /var/mailer2/mailer.php
```

code:

```
    $hash = md5( rand(0,1000) );
    $to = $email; 
    $subject = 'Signup | Verification';
    $message = '

                Thanks for signing up!
                Your account has been created, you can login with the following credentials after you have activated your account by pressing the url below.

                ------------------------
                Username: '.$username.'
                Password: '.$password1.'
                ------------------------

                Please click this link to activate your account:
                email='.$email.'&hash='.$hash.'

                ';
    $headers = "From: donotreply@domain.com\r\n";
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What ideas should we have without you posting your settings for mail sending? PLease check your php configuration for that. Thanks.

Comment: First idea is just "did you get the right email address" (I know, but it pays to check). Second is "can you access the maillog on the server?" - that may give you some information. Final thought is "try a service like mailgun.io to act as your SMTP server" - often mail hosts will just block anything that looks like spam, which includes mail servers that they can't communicate with themselves.

Comment: Oh, and did you try other addresses? Get something from fakemailgenerator or 10minutemail and see if the mail shows up there.

Comment: who knows; maybe they blacklisted you.

Comment: @arkascha Posted the configuration. Though not sure if that's all there is.

Comment: @samlev But shouldn't mail servers put it into spam folder instead of blocking it? I mean how do they know if I'm gonna consider it a spam or not?

Comment: mail servers do what they like, especially the big ones! If your server ip has been associated with spam they might just outright block any mail originated from it. This is why mailing companies exist. A decent free (up to a point) one is mandrill

Comment: @Steve Especially `mandrill` is famous to have its IP addresses appear on blacklists several times a week :-) Which is not surprising, actually, since it is a decent spammer platform in the end.

Comment: @SaulTigh You might want to think about setting up your own smtp server, that has a few advantages, but obviously also requires effort for the setup: you ahve a good queuing system, so your `mail()` call returns fast and reliable and you get log files documenting the messages, especially the reasons for denial.

Comment: It may be worth looking at the headers that the email has when it arrives at Gmail. Ensure that no headers are present that would enable it to identify that PHP sent the message.Also have you checked the from email address to see if a bounceback occurs,